# Error fetching contacts:, [AxiosError: Network Error], Can someone help me with this error

Tags: mongodb, react-native, mobile, expo, chat

Error fetching contacts:, [AxiosError: Network Error]
at .expo\screens\Chat.js:null in fetchData
at node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in asyncGeneratorStep
at node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:null in Promise$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in queueReactNativeMicrotask
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer

- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

this is the error and API routes http://192.168.0.126:8082 is this and can get information. The error is chat.

I tried to configure the https to postman and the display is cannot get

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a network error while trying to fetch contacts in your react native app. this is likely using axios for fetching data.

check network connectivity

verify API Endpoints

verify CORS

test it on post man

inspect network requests

Comment: I already check the network connectivity, verify API Endpoints and the cors but when I test it on post man the message is Cannot GET /auth/allusers

Comment: Then you may need to review your API Configuration and ensure that the endpoint is correctly defined and accessible. Just gimme a update on this cheers !!!!